# WHO package not working in R?

Tags: r, package

I have been using WHO package in R to get data from WHO database without problems for the last several weeks. Yesterday I found that I could no longer do it. I reproduced the error in different machines using different R versions, running from R itself and from Rstudio, Mac and Windows alike...

Example with 2 of the variables I want to request.

```
library(WHO)
socio_econ <- c("WHS7_143", "WHS9_95")
SECON <- lapply(socio_econ, function(t) get_data(t))
```

Here's the error:

> Error in get_result(url) : Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).

Answer (score 0):

NOT AN ANSWER JUST SHOWING A DEBUGGING METHOD FOR THE OP

```
httr::with_verbose(get_data("WHS7_143"))

-> GET /gho/athena/api/GHO/WHS7_143?format=json&profile=simple HTTP/1.1
-> Host: apps.who.int
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.51.0 r-curl/2.0 httr/1.2.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Cookie: TS01ac0ef4=015dd60f3e63259629be28ff562fb98a7b99c500697d6a49e2671ad07b50034231788b7dd97944f7f6fd363c9ef2b32a1a34c37a22
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> 
<- HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
<- Date: Mon, 01 May 2017 20:46:40 GMT
<- Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
<- Content-Length: 1298
<- Via: 1.1 ghodata.who.int
<- Connection: close
<- Set-Cookie: TS01ac0ef4=015dd60f3e63259629be28ff562fb98a7b99c500697d6a49e2671ad07b50034231788b7dd97944f7f6fd363c9ef2b32a1a34c37a22; Path=/
<- 
Error in get_result(url) : Internal Server Error (HTTP 500).
```

It's definitely something happening server-side, but it could be that the API changed and the pkg has not updated yet.

Hitting the inferred URL directly:

[image]

suggests it's an Java server error on their end.

Comment: So...I tried to go manual and seems that the actual link the package should hit is not working, throwing error HTTP 500... http://apps.who.int/gho/data/view.main.HEALTHEXPRATIOWBGLOBAL

Comment: yep. pasted a screen shot similar to that as you were commenting :-)